# JSPM not able to download github packages behind the proxy

Tags: javascript, github, npm, proxy, jspm

I am using http proxy between JSPM and socks tunnel.

At the mooment the npm packages are downloading, but jspm can not install the github packages.

The error I am getting is coming from
*project/node_modules/jspm-github/github.js*, when I run for exmaple *jspm install github:aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive@3.2.6*

```
err  Error on getPackageConfig for github:aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

My .npmrc in project:

```
loglevel=error
progress=false
save-prefix='~'
strict-ssl=false
registry=https://nexus.vpro.nl/content/groups/npm-all/
audit=false
```

My .zprofile

```
# HTTP Proxy
httpProxyServer=http://127.0.0.1:8080
httpsProxyServer=http://127.0.0.1:8080

export http_proxy=$httpProxyServer
export https_proxy=$httpsProxyServer
export HTTP_PROXY=$httpProxyServer
export HTTPS_PROXY=$httpsProxyServer


export npm_config_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
export npm_config_https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
```

and my .gitconfig

```
[http]
        proxy = http://127.0.0.1:8080
        sslVerify = false
[https]
        proxy = http://127.0.0.1:8080
        sslVerify = false
[url "https://"]
        insteadOf = git:/
```

Comment: For other readers, check ongoing discussions on github: https://github.com/jspm/github/issues/129